# Why "move semantics" rather than simply memcpy?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Given the following code:

```
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type storage_t;

//this moves the back of src to the back of dst:
void push_popped(std::list<storage_t> & dstLst, std::list<storage_t> & srcLst)
{
  auto & src = srcLst.back();
  dstLst.push_back(storage_t());
  auto & dst = dstLst.back();
  std::memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(T));
  srcLst.pop_back();
}
```

I'm aware of 3 reasons why this approach is not, in general, correct (even though it avoids calling `src->~T()` and so avoids double-reclamation of `T`'s resources).

1. object members of type `U*` that point to other `U` members of the same object
2. hidden class members may need to be updated (vtable, for instance)
3. the system needs to record that no `T` exists anymore at `src` and that a `T` does now exist at `dst`

(These are mentioned here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/655730-c-stdmove-vs-stdmemcpy/#entry5148523.)

Assuming that `T` is not a type whose memory address is a property of its state (`std::mutex` or `std::condition_variable`, for instance), are these the only issues with this approach?  Or are there other things that could go wrong?  I'd like a description of the unknown issues.

I'd like to think I have an "object relocation semantics" developed, but I'd rather not ask people to consider it if there's an obvious hole in it.

Comment: I think member pointers and vtables (which probably are mere offsets) are not the issue; normal pointers pointing into src are though. In general any class with non-trivial [copy/assignment] [edit: actually, *move*] semantics will fail with memcpy.

Comment: The short answer is "it is undefined behavior. It breaks assumptions that an optimizing compiler may rely on, so it can result in all sorts of unpredictable bugs". There is no finite limited and predefined list of "possible issues with this approach". What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: By the way, for this particular example, the correct solution is to use `splice`.

Comment: @t-c : Agree.  I just needed a way to avoid concerns about memory size, alignment, and management, and this was the tersest way I could figure to accomplish that.

Comment: @jalf : I'm guessing that when move semantics were being discussed by the standards committee, probably several of these kinds of issues were brought up.  Given that, in the place where I originally encountered the discussion of these issues (in old boost discussions about variant implementation, but they were linked via a url that is no longer available and I was unable to locate it) there was some exasperation expressed at having to repeatedly discuss them, I wanted to try to get a list available at a non-dead url that I could use as a general roadmap and discussion help.

Comment: @PeterSchneider : I've attempted to clarify the "class member pointers" phrase.  Pointers from other objects into `src` are an issue that is independent of copy/assign/move semantics.

Answer (score 7):

The concept of "trivially copyable" implies that a memcpy is safe.  You can test if a type is trivially copyable via a trait in `std`.

It includes the idea that destroying it is a noop; in your case, you want destruction to not be a noop, but rather not done on the source, while being done on the dest.

The concept of "move-and-destroy-source" has been proposed in the C++1z standardization process independent of the "trivially copyable" concept.  It was proposed for exception safety; there are types for which a move-construct is not exception-safe, but a move-construct-and-destroy-source would be.  And there are thorny problems involving exceptions and container allocations that make a noexcept move-ctor operation very valuable.

If that gets into the standard, then a trivially-copyable-if-you-don't-destroy-source concept could also be added to the standard, if it proves valuable.

It wouldn't apply to everything move semantics can enhance, and it may require effort on the part of programmers (how the compiler can work out that "it is ok to elide a destroyer" is not going to be easy; all non-trivial non-structural properties of Turing Machine behavior are intractable.)

Comment: Sounds like [N4158](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4158.pdf)? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @dyp nope, that's the one.

Comment: @Yakk : Yes, I'm considering something similar to this.  The two shortcomings I see in that proposal are a)no support for auto stored objects, and b)no opportunity for the system to "manage its books" (#s 2 and 3 in the original question's list).

Answer (score 2):

Why use Copy constructor instead of `std::memcpy` ? 
The Move constructor/move assignment oeprator gives you encapsulated opratunity to do some other usefull stuff when you move an object - logging, cleaning up, etc.

preformance wise - in many cases the compiler can optimize many moves to just one (imagin many functions that simply returns some object from one another). with `memcpy` their abilty is much more restricted.

and finally - because C++ is not about moving bytes around - it's about using objects as a basis for your program.

Comment: performance: I need to make sure my proposed solution wouldn't disallow (and might even enhance opportunities for) optimization of multiple moves.  Thanks, David!